# how to enumerate all the div tag with same id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, enumeration

I have web-pages based on widget and I have given all the div the same ID attribute. 
After the page is loaded, I want to enumerate all the div element which matches the ID element 'widget'. I am using **jQuery**.

Then I want to get the internal div attribute within the 'widget' div which shall be used as a tooltip.

```
<div id="widget" class="span-8  "  >

<h2><a href="">Example.com</a></h2>
<ul>
        <li><h3><a href="example.com">Example News 1</a></h3>
    <div id="tooltip-content">              
        <div class="published">Thu Jul 8, 2010</div>
        <div class="content">
            This detail news 1 shown only on tooltip.. 
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li><h3><a href="example.com">Example News 2</a></h3>
    <div id="tooltip-content">              
        <div class="published">Thu Jul 8, 2010</div>
        <div class="content">
            This detail news 2 shown only on tooltip.. 
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>               
</ul>
```

Basically I want to get the all the widgets with id 'widget'( I have around 20 widgets per page) and get all the div which id matches 'tooltip-content' within widget. One widget has 5 or 6 tooltip-content.  Can you help me to enumerate the divs?

Comment: you should not have duplicate `ids` they are unique identifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically element id's should always be unique, yes you can have elements with the same id but you'll run into problems like this. Where jQuery's selector engine is only expecting one element with a given id, so what will end up happening is it will find the first element and ignore the rest.

What you should do is give them all the same class eg

```
class="widget"
```

and the the selector would be

```
$(".widget")
```

EDIT: ah yeah for some reason I thought you mentioned you were using jQuery. but here's a function that will get all elements by ID that doesn't require any library's

```
/*
 * ElementsById
 *
 * Author: Diego Perini
 * Updated: 07/12/2006
 * Version: 0.0 (from parent)
 *
 * Extracted from latest IPORT/STYLER engines.
 *
 * Returns an array of elements with specified ID.
 */
function ElementsById($id) {
    var c = 0, i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    var nodes=[], storage = arguments.callee.storage;
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var length = elements.length;
    if (storage &&
        storage.nodes &&
        storage.length == length &&
        storage.first == elements[0] &&
        storage.last == elements[length-1]) {
        k = $id;
        while (storage.nodes[k]) {
            nodes[nodes.length] = storage.nodes[k];
            k = $id + '*' + (++i);
        }
    } else {
        storage = { };
        storage.nodes = { };
        storage.length = 0;
        storage.first = elements[0];
        storage.last = elements[length - 1];
        while (length > i) {
            c = elements[i];
            if ((k = c.id) == $id) {
                nodes[nodes.length] = c;
                if (storage.nodes[k]) {
                   k = c.id + '*' + (++j);
                }
            }
            i++;
            storage.nodes[k] = c;
            storage.length++;
        }
        arguments.callee.storage = storage;
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

Comment: @RueTheWhirled, Thanks for details.. Then how to enumerate by class names? The final goal is to get all the elements and since I am newbie to html and jquery and javascript, I am trying to do things just to work..

Comment: Might help if I can ask you if you are you using jQuery first?

Comment: Yes.. I am using jQuery.. Thanks

Comment: OK well, first off you should give all the elements you want to enumerate through the same class, so in your case widget and as Dean 'codeka' Harding states below you can then call  
$(".widget").each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass('red'); // exampleof adding red class to each element
});
to iterate thought them

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each/
more documentation on jQuery .each.

Just re-reading your question though realised you mentioned you want to enumerate through all the divs with tooltip-content as id? if so you should also change those to classes instead of id's and then you could do 
$(".widget .tooltip-content').each(function(){
 $(this).addClass('red'); //do stuff
});

Comment: This is possibly the worst unobfuscated Javascript code I've ever seen in my life. First, it's wrong to have multiple instances of the same ID in a document and it leads to unexpected behavior, so writing a way to access all those elements is undefined at best and in any case, also wrong. Second, the code itself is very stupidly written; has this Diego Perini ever heard of an array? I was tempted to give a -1 until I saw that you didn't write it, but I'm still not sure why your answer was selected or why chose to give this code snippet. IMO it's a candidate for The Daily WTF.

Answer (score 7):

IDs are supposed to be unique within a document; you are only supposed to have one element per ID. See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp)

> The id must be unique within the HTML document.

What you want to do is use a `class` attribute on each of those elements, and then select based on a class name. If you are using a framework such as Prototype, jQuery or Ext (or another one that you prefer), there should be a method to select elements by CSS selector or by class name. I recommend you add a class called `widget` to each of those elements, and give them unique IDs instead,

Answer (score 6):

> I have given all the div the same ID

This is your problem. The id, by definition, needs to be unique. If it's not unique then you run into all sorts of problems (like not being able to enumerate them easily, for example). Instead, you can use the `class` attribute (a single element can have multiple classes by separating them with spaces so `class="widget span-8"` is fine).

You could then use jQuery's class-based selector for easy enumeration:

```
$(".widget").each(function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Most web browsers handle the "id" attribute as a special attribute which is meant to be a single hash lookup.  You shouldn't assign the same id to multiple elements.

I'd recommend assigning a different attribute, perhaps "widget_id".

Once you do that, you can enumerate all elements with a given "widget_id" via:

```
$(div[widget_id="tooltip-content"]);
```