# aligning rows of nested tables

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 3 nested tables next to eachother. The first table (in first column) includes rows with the parameter names, the following 3 tables (will) include the values of these parameters for (3) various scenarios (filled in by a javascript function).

I'm not very strong and experienced on styling html and was wondering how to set the height of the rows properly so all values in a row of main table 'resulttable' will align properly? In particular when the second row can contain a number of productnames below eachother, which number can vary for each of the 3 columns (e.g., the heigh of this row can vary and is determined by the column with the most productnames).

(ps: I have chosen for this particular nested table structure as the user must be able to click on one the 3 tables to have some further action performed.)

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

html (style and body) code:

```
<style>
.thead_rb td
{
height:20px;
}

.tbody_rb td
{
height:20px;
}
</style>


<body>
<table class="resulttable">
<tr> <!--3 tables each containing a resultbox next to eachother-->
<td>
    <table class="hideElement" id="rb_valnames">
    <thead class="thead_rb"> <!--empty -->
        <tr>
            <th> calculation </th> <!--empty -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody_rb"> <!--includes names of calculated values including units-->
        <tr> <td> product names </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td> cost  </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td> revenues </td> </tr>
    </tbody> 
    </table> <!--class="hideElement" id="rb_valnames" -->
</td> <!--table resultbox 0-->
<td>
    <table class="hideElement" id="rb_box0">
    <thead class="thead_rb"> <!--first resultbox includes NO checbox -->
        <tr>
            <th> Result </th> <!--first resultbox includes NO checbox -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody_rb"> <!--includes results of resultbox 0-->
        <tr> <td id="fld_product_rb0">  </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td id="fld_cost_rb0">  </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td id="fld_revenues_rb0">  </td> </tr>    
    </tbody> 
    </table> <!--class="hideElement" id="rb_box0" -->
</td> <!--table resultbox 0-->
<td>
    <table class="hideElement" id="rb_box1">
    <thead class="thead_rb"> <!--includes checbox to keep results -->
        <tr>
            <th> <label for="keeprbresult[1]"> Previous result 1</label> <input type="checkbox" class="hideElement" id="check_rb1" name="keeprbresult[]" value=""> <br> </th> <!-- checkbox to keep alternative result in checkbox 1--> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody_rb"> <!--includes results of resultbox 1-->
        <tr> <td id="fld_product_rb0">  </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td id="fld_cost_rb0">  </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td id="fld_revenues_rb0">  </td> </tr>    
    </tbody> 
    </table> <!--class="hideElement" id="rb_box1" -->
</td> <!--table resultbox 1-->
</tr>
</table> <!--resulttable-->
</body>
```

Comment: It'll be a pain to do it like this. You really should find a way to have only one table. Also, you shouldn't have the same ID at multiple places.

Comment: It would be helpful here if your table actually contained content (unless the problem is your template code, only provide generated HTML).  Empty tags make it difficult to determine what the appropriate markup should be.

Comment: thnx for your comments. I actually had such flat table structure at the start, till I concluded that I want the customer be able to click on each of the areas (what I have defined as nested tables in columns 2,3 and 4) after which some action by javascript will be performed. With the flat table structure I dont see how to create a onclick function (something like $('#nestedtable').click(function(){//some code})...

Comment: Agreed with @cimmanon, it'd help if we could get some data in that table to help with alignment.

Comment: @cimmanon: As mentioned those tags are empty as they will be filled by a javascript function. Fields in the first 2 rows contain some text, fields in the following 2 rows contain some numbers.

Comment: Right now, this is a misuse of tables.  It would have been better to ask how to get the JavaScript to work with a single table, rather than how to fix the appearance of poor markup.

Comment: TRhanks all for your comments. I actually just found the solution within javascript (also referring to cimmanon's latest comment) using the flat table; use a specific class (say 'x') for a set (x) of td elements, and the relating jquery selector $(".x") - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225708/how-to-enumerate-all-the-div-tag-with-same-id